# Android InstrumentationTestCase runTestOnUiThread not invoked

Tags: android, android-testing

I'm trying to run very simple code on UI thread in InstrumentationTestCase, but it never invoked. For example, this test passes. How can I run it correctly?

```
public class Test1 extends InstrumentationTestCase {

    @Test
    public void testUI() throws Throwable {
        final CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);

        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               fail();
            }

        });

        try {
            signal.await(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // wait for callback
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```